# installing Tinycore to compact flash: grub not found

Tags: grub2, flash

I've been following this tutorial: [Installing Tinycore on to a Compact Flash card](http://www.parkytowers.me.uk/thin/Linux/TinycoreCF.shtml). Everything goes fine until I get to this part:

```
 grub --device-map=grub-device.map
```

where I get an error: `grub is not installed`.

I've tried this command:

```
apt-cache policy grub2 grub-pc
```

And the output is:

```
grub2:  
Installed: none  

grub-pc:  
Installed: none
```

I can't understand what is happening.
I've tried:

```
apt-get update  
apt-get purge grub grub-pc grub-common
```

And then:

```
apt-get install grub-common grub-pc  
update-grub
```

But it doesn't work at all.

Could someone help me or suggest something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it uninstalling grub2 and reinstalling grub, grub-common and grub-pc with the help of synaptic.
Everything goes fine now :)

I just used synaptics: Marked the options "grub-common","grub-pc" and "grub-pc-bin" and installed them.(This seems to substitute grub2 with grub-legacy).

Then I could continue with the tutorial with no problem, and I managed to have tinycore installed in my compact flash.